# Material Select Initialization in vue.js

Tags: javascript, material-design, vue.js

I am building an app using vue.js with Material Design Bootstrap (mdb)  - http://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/material-select/. According to the documentation, for me to use the `select` styling, I need to overwrite the standard `select` by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mdb-select').material_select();
});
```

However, I am not sure where to place the above code in my vue.js component. I tried putting it in my `create` method:

```
<template>

    <select class="mdb-select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>

</template>

<script>

module.exports = {

  created: function () {
    $('.mdb-select').material_select();
  },

}

</script>
```

However, I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function`.

Does anyone know where I should perform the initialization instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lifecycle documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) says:

> created
>
> Called synchronously after the instance is created. At this stage, the
>   instance has finished processing the options which means the following
>   have been set up: data observation, computed properties, methods,
>   watch/event callbacks. However, DOM compilation has not been started,
>   and **the `$el` property will not be available yet**.

You need the DOM element to have been created, so you want the `ready` phase. Also, you should use `$(this.$el).find('.mdb-select')` to restrict your selection to the current element.

Comment: Just a heads up: you'd want `this.$el`, not just `$el`.

Comment: @BillCriswell Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Hi - I just tried placing `$(this.$el).find('.mdb-select').material_select()` in the `ready()` function but I'm still getting the same  `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function` error... any thoughts?

Comment: @user1547174 Check that the material select is properly included before you apply Vue.